# Android material-date-picker, change colors without using theme

Tags: android, materialdatepicker

I'm using material date picker, and would like to change the accentcolor (for header background, selected date and buttons), but I don't know the color until runtime (as it's user defined and coming from an external source), so can't define a theme in advance.

(I'd rather not use an external library, as I'm using this in multiple places already and I want to keep things consistent.)

Any ideas?